# How can I receive this request in another server using curl and php

Tags: php, curl

I'm new here so please be patient, This is my request code, I want to write another piece of code in another server that will be accepting it and returning an xml 7101 success code using php and curl. How do I write code in a receiving server. This is actually API  that I will be using to exchange data between my system and another remote system stored in clouds I have managed to send request successfully but I have stuck at receiving their requests, I have spent an entire week on it please help me out on receiving the requests when they send them to me.

success code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<gepgBillSubReqAck>
    <TrxStsCode>7101</TrxStsCode>
</gepgBillSubReqAck>
```

the request code is this,

```
<?php

    //Bill Request 
    $content ="<gepgBillSubReq>
        <BillHdr>
            <SpCode>SP103</SpCode>
            <RtrRespFlg>true</RtrRespFlg>
        </BillHdr>
        <BillTrxInf>
            <BillId>1812022009968</BillId>
            <SubSpCode>1001</SubSpCode>
            <SpSysId>TANESCO001</SpSysId>
            <BillAmt>1180</BillAmt>
            <MiscAmt>0</MiscAmt>
            <BillExprDt>2017-12-31T23:59:59</BillExprDt>
            <PyrId>5144AA5914</PyrId>
            <PyrName>test</PyrName>
            <BillDesc>Bill Number 5913</BillDesc>
            <BillGenDt>2017-12-21T09:39:00</BillGenDt>
            <BillGenBy>Bhstenkubo</BillGenBy>
            <BillApprBy>Bhstenkubo</BillApprBy>
            <PyrCellNum/>
            <PyrEmail/>
            <Ccy>TZS</Ccy>
            <BillEqvAmt>1180</BillEqvAmt>
            <RemFlag>false</RemFlag>
            <BillPayOpt>1</BillPayOpt>
            <BillItems>
                <BillItem>
                    <BillItemRef>5144AA5914</BillItemRef>
                    <UseItemRefOnPay>N</UseItemRefOnPay>
                    <BillItemAmt>1180</BillItemAmt>
                    <BillItemEqvAmt>1180</BillItemEqvAmt>
                    <BillItemMiscAmt>0</BillItemMiscAmt>
                    <GfsCode>140316</GfsCode>
                </BillItem>
            </BillItems>
        </BillTrxInf>
    </gepgBillSubReq>";

    $resultCurlPost = "";

    $serverIp = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    $uri = "/XXX/XXX/qrequest"; //this is for qrequest

    echo "Message ready to GePG:"."\n".$content."\n";

    $ch = curl_init($serverIp.$uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                        'Content-Type:application/xml',
                        'Gepg-Com:default.sp.in',
                        'Gepg-Code:SP103',
                        'Content-Length:'.strlen($content))
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 50);

    //Capture returned content from GePG
    $resultCurlPost = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    //$resultCurlPost=$data; 
    if(!empty($resultCurlPost)){

        echo "\n\n";
        echo "Received Response\n";
        echo  $resultCurlPost;
        echo "\n";              
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No result Returned"."\n";
    }

?>
```

Comment: You don't need to do much. Once your have your receiving web server up and running in the cloud its natural behaviour is to receive POST data and respond to it. The most basis variant would be a PHP page that echos your XML request. It would look like this: `<?php var_dump($_POST);` Yes, that's all that is needed. Of course you need to do something with the request, but that's a whole other matter.

Comment: To process XML, SimpleXML is probably the easiest library to get started with.  If you look at some examples of processing AJAX requests, this should give you some short examples.

Comment: Thanks KIKO Software, Nigel Ren for timely response I'm currently making the changes according to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you guys for contributing I found a solution, I used file_get_contents("php://input"); on the receiving server and so far it is working fine.